# How to handle this kind of situation?

Tags: vue.js, mobile, mobile-website

I need to develop a web project for mobile devices. And I met an awkard situation.

This is customer's desire. A user come to the bar. He scan QR image with a phone camera, a banner appears to ask if he want to open the browser menu or an app.

Well, as a web developer this seems absolutely impossible. But the problem is that the customer claims that this is the most common UX those days. I am not sure what does it mean. Have you seen any kind of thing like this and know how to do it? Or is it just a customer's imagination?

Even if they implemented this via app, I just want to know how they were able to show the banner on a camera. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: This is absolutely possible. I think there's just a communication breakdown between you and the client. A QR code can contain a multitude of different data. In your case, having it link to a static landing page that offers the "Browse Menu" or "Open in App" buttons that are being described. The 'Open in App' can deep link to your Application on the phone if installed, otherwise fall back to the App Store to install it.

Comment: Oh, that's was really clear. I just forgot that QR code can include a lot of information. But is it possible for a camera to show the banner automatically? It can scan the code and get the link, of course. But showing banners?

Comment: I'm not aware of any feature that can create interactable buttons within the Camera its self other than AR applications.