# How to predict the QR scan result of the mobile camera?

Tags: vue.js, mobile, qr-code, mobile-website

Thanks to the help of [Ohgodwhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206267/ohgodwhy), I realized that it is possible to use QR code for a advertising, too.([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898301/how-to-handle-this-kind-of-situation)) Just scanning code shows the banner with options of Open Browser and Install App, it's really amazing.

I really want to realize this. I want to do it in my vue project. The problem is that I am not sure about the preview content of the link of the QR code. I am just embedding the link. The scanned result might show the link and hopefully the preview of the link.

But I am not sure how it would look like. Preview of the link are different on different platforms. Can you help me how to guess the content that will be shown by the mobile device as the banner when it successfully scanned the QR code?